# What is the effectiveness of using the compatibility feature for older operating systems in Windows XP, Vista, 7 and 8?

Tags: c++, batch-file, cross-platform, adapter, compatibility

I've been trying to research why certain compatibility features differ based on operating system so I can program a patch. I'm using the compatibility settings in the registry for Windows 95 to run a game (that of which the game was produced on) in each system. In Windows XP, the game runs perfectly. None of the scenes lag, and the sound works just as well as the scenes. I'm unsure of how it runs in Windows Vista, but in Windows 7 & 8 the compatibility feature breaks the game. I used a VM to run XP, but that doesn't effect the game's playability; real XP users have tested it. Whenever I play the game using the Win95 setting for compatibility in 7 & 8, everything lags. The music doesn't slow down during gameplay, but the graphics do. During cutscenes, they literally break. Everything pixelates, white noise and static increases volume, and the video lags every two seconds.

I therein tested it in Ubuntu Linux via WINE, and it runs better than it does in XP. I just had to use the alsa sound driver. What changed? If so, is it programmatically fixable? I'm using an amalgamation of C++, Batch and Java. 
If it is necessary, the video game is entitled "The Neverhood." 
Thanks.

Comment: Excellent game.  On Win 7 with XP compatibility, are you achieving XP mode via [Virtual PC with an XP VM](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002)?

Comment: I'm not using XP compatibility; I'm using a VM to run the game THROUGH compatibility mode for Windows 95. Meaning [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-compatibility-mode/). I'm trying to test the effectiveness of each. Depending on the OS, the compatibility mode seems to have different effects on the game.

Comment: This question isn't appropriate here.  Use the Neverhood user forum, there's a [thread there](http://z11.invisionfree.com/Neverhood_Community/index.php?showtopic=704&st=0) that discusses workarounds for your problem.

Comment: The compatibility feature is just scratching the surface of compatibility in Windows. There is a tool called "Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit (ACT)" that has more, but it's a world in itself, maybe that can help. For example: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc749004.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compatibility feature available in the shell is just scratching the surface of the ["Application Compatibility"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/aa905066.aspx) subject in Windows.

There is a tool called ["Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit (ACT)"](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc722367.aspx) (that exist since Windows XP exist I believe) that has much more to offer, so maybe that can help.

For example here are some compatibility settings for [Graphics Control Issues](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc749004.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I currently play "The Neverhood" on Win7 x64 without any visual problem, you are right when I played on Win7 for first time (4 years ago) was a headache and a little tricky to do the correct compatibility flags for each win version but finally I wrote this reg code for Win7 and worked for me while 4 years, sure it will work for you too:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers]
"C:\\Folder\\nhc.exe"="# WIN95 256COLOR 640X480 DISABLEDWM"
```

- Where "C:\\Folder\\nhc.exe" of course is the path to your Neverhood. (Notice the double backslashes)

that flags means: *Change Display color to 256 colors, change display resolution to 640x480, disable Themes service (DWM Service)*.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Nope. In fact, I thank you for adding in the `640X480 DISABLEDWM` part, but I'm still getting laggy cutscenes. I've already used this code (again, without the two parts you contributed), but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: There seems to be a click with Win7 x64 that allows it to work. I've had testers of that operating system run with ease.

Comment: Whay you mean witch a "click"?

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant but in my game crack (a reg file) I saw this two reg values called "KBPS...", maybe are relationed with all this or your lags, if you will try it (PS: Delete the wow643node from the path if you are on x86): Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\DreamWorks Interactive\Neverhood]
"KBPS_OTHER"=dword:00002800
"KBPS"=dword:00002800         also maybe a dxdiag.exe for your 2D graphics wold be nice to check.

Comment: A click, as in it seems to work for all people on Win7 x64. I'm running on Win8 x64. Also, could you please edit your answer & further explain what your suggestion is?

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer the question directly, but if you want to improve performance of The Neverhood, change the compatibility to run in Windows 95 - then switch all other options ON, except the bottom three. This helps to make the game as fast and smooth as possible.